# Undefined type: foo.FormBean at process.jsp

Tags: eclipse, weblogic-10.x

I get this error message in eclipse when I try to start eclipse `Undefined type: foo.FormBean at process.jsp`

Here is my process.jsp file. I am working on a demo user login and  authentication system.
Does and one know what this means

`

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%! 
    ResourceBundle bundle =null;
    public void jspInit() {
       bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("forms");
      }
%>
<jsp:useBean id="formHandler" class="foo.FormBean" scope="request">
<jsp:setProperty name="formHandler" property="*"/>
</jsp:useBean>
<% 
   if (formHandler.validate()) {
%>
    <jsp:forward page="<%=bundle.getString(\"process.success\")%>"/>
<%
   }  else {
%>
    <jsp:forward page="<%=bundle.getString(\"process.retry\")%>"/>
<%
   }
%>  `
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line which causes the error is:

```
    <jsp:useBean id="formHandler" class="foo.FormBean" scope="request">
```

The foo.FormBean is undefined.

In order to fix this issue put the compiled FormBean classes under WEB-INF/classes/foo/ and add the <%@ page import="foo.*" %> in the process jsp.

BR,
Tolis